# calculation on Ito's Lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have a question on the calculation on Ito's Lemma:

${{Y}_{t}}={{t}^{{{W}_{t}}}}$

solve for $d{{Y}_{t}}$

the following is my solution

[\begin{align}
  & d{{Y}_{t}}=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial {{W}_{t}}}d{{W}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}Y}{\partial {{W}^{2}}}{{\left( d{{W}_{t}} \right)}^{2}} \\ 
 & ={{W}_{t}}{{t}^{{{W}_{t}}-1}}dt+{{t}^{{{W}_{t}}}}\ln td{{W}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}{{t}^{{{W}_{t}}}}{{\left( \ln t \right)}^{2}}dt \\ 
 & ={{t}^{{{W}_{t}}}}\ln td{{W}_{t}}+{{t}^{{{W}_{t}}}}(\frac{{{W}_{t}}}{t}+\frac{1}{2}{{\left( \ln t \right)}^{2}})dt \\ 
\end{align}]

is my solution correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is correct.